# Django: How to test for 'HttpResponsePermanentRedirect'

Tags: python, django, http

I'm writing some tests for my django app.In my view,it redirects to some other url using 'HttpResponseRedirect'.So how can I test that?

Comment: Could you elaborate more? What do you exactly mean test that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
from django.test.client import Client

class MyTestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_my_method(self):

        client = Client()
        response = client.post('/some_url/')

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 301)
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(response, HttpResponsePermanentRedirect))
        self.assertEqual(response.META['HTTP_LOCATION'], '/url_we_expect_to_be_redirected_to/')
```

There are other attributes of the response that might be interesting to test. If you are unsure what is on the object then you can always do a

```
print dir(response)
```

**EDIT FOR CURRENT VERSIONS OF DJANGO**

It's a bit simpler now, just do:

```
    self.assertEqual(response.get('location'), '/url/we/expect')
```

I would also suggest using reverse to look up the url you expect from a name, if it is a url in your app anyway.

Comment: The last line throws an error in Django 1.4: `AttributeError: 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'META'`

Comment: Yup, changed in 1.4 it seems. Instead you would compare `response.get('location')` against your desired redirect url.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `raise Exception(dir(response))` to find out what us available?

Answer (score 21):

The Django `TestCase` class has a method [`assertRedirects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects) that you can use.

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_my_redirect(self): 
        """Tests that /my-url/ permanently redirects to /next-url/"""
        response = self.client.get('/my-url/')
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/next-url/', status_code=301)
```

Status code 301 checks that it's a permanent redirect.

Comment: Is this working for anyone using Django `<=1.5.2`? It seems I've hit [this bug](https://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-webtest/issue/8/assertredirects-response-code-was-302).

Comment: @JonasG.Drange you are linking to a bug report for version 1.5.2 of the app django-webtest, not Django itself. In my original answer, I did suggest that you could use `follow=False` in the get request to stop the client from following the redirect. That was incorrect, so I've removed it. The `assertRedirect` method always checks the status page, as documented. There is a ticket [#20919](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20919) to allow `assertRedirects` to not load the target page.

Answer (score 1):

In django 1.6, you could use(**not recommended**):

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect

class YourTest(TestCase):
    def test_my_redirect(self):
        response = self.client.get('/url-you-want-to-test/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 301)# premant 301, temporary 302
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(response, HttpResponsePermanentRedirect))
        self.assertEqual(response.get('location'), 'http://testserver/redirect-url/')
```

instead, following is more powerful and concise and no `http://testserver/` need

```
from django.test import TestCase

class YourTest(TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        response = self.client.get('/url-you-want-to-test/')
        self.assertRedirects(
            response, '/redirect-url/',status_code=301,target_status_code=200)
```