# How to test Django redirect from view class

Tags: python, django, testing, django-unittest

I'm learning Django atm and I am stuck with creating a simple test case.

How I can test the following view? If the user is already logged in it redirects him to list view.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class LoginView(TemplateView):
    """
    Base class for client area login.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Display login form, only if user is not yet authenticated.
        Otherwise redirect to tickets index.
        :param request:
        :param args:
        :param kwargs:
        :return:
        """
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect(reverse('tickets:index'))

        form = AuthenticationForm()

        return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

So far the test I have created looks like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AnonymousUser
from app.account.views import LoginView


class TestLoginForm(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        """
        Set up environment
        :return:
        """
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username="test", password="test123", email="test@gmail.com")
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

    def tearDown(self):
        """
        Clean created user object
        :return:
        """
        self.user.delete()
        self.factory = None

    def test_login_form_redirect(self):
        """
        Test login redirect
        :return:
        """


        request = self.factory.get(reverse('account:login'))
        request.user = AnonymousUser()

        view = LoginView()
        response = view.get(request=request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        request.user = self.user
        response = view.get(request=request)
        self.assertRedirects(response, expected_url=reverse('tickets:index'), status_code=302, target_status_code=200)
```

The first assertation passed, but the second where the user should be redirected if already has logged in throws this error

```
AttributeError: 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'client'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I have managed to make successful test case, with following code

```
def test_login_form_redirect(self):
    """
    Test login redirect
    :return:
    """

    self.client.logout()

    response = self.client.get(reverse('account:login'))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    self.assertTrue(self.client.login(username='test', password='test123'))
    response = self.client.get(reverse('account:login'))
    self.assertRedirects(response, expected_url=reverse('tickets:index'), status_code=302, target_status_code=200)
```

Comment: You've switched from unit testing to e2e testing. Check this answer for correct way of checking redirections in unit tests: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11683427/2638796